# Let n be a positive integer. Compute the conjugacy classes of subgroups of order 2 in GLn($\mathbb{C}$)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Compute the conjugacy classes of subgroups of
order $2$ in $GL_n$($\mathbb{C}$). $\mathbb{C}$ is the field of complex numbers.

I'll start my reasoning and please correct/add to it. Thanks:

Let H be a subgroup of order two in $GLn(\mathbb{C})$ and let $A∈H$ Since $GLn(\mathbb{C})$ only contains invertible matrices, let $X∈GLn(\mathbb{C})$ . Since $GLn(\mathbb{C})$ is closed, $XAX^{-1}=Y$. So $Y$ is similar to $A$ and $Y$ is conjugate to $A$.

What's confusing me is how to count the conjugacy classes of $A$.  The identity has only itself in its conjugacy class. But $A$ seems to have many, many more.

Comment: Do you mean *elements* of order $2$? Have you learned about the Jordan normal form?

Comment: No, the question asks for subgroups.  My linear algebra is bad, no doubts there.  Let $H$ be a subgroup of order two in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ and let $A \in H$.  Since $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ only contains invertible matrices, let $X \in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ .  Since $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is closed, $XAX^{-!} = Y$.  So $Y$ is similar to $A$ and $Y$ is conjugate to $A$.

What's confusing me is there seem to be an infinite number of matrices $X$ that will "generate" conjugate matrices for $A$.

Comment: Yes, a conjugacy class of invertible matrices will generally have an infinite number of elements (and every element of a conjugacy class is a representative).

Answer (score 1):

A subgroup of $G$ of order $2$ looks like $\{e,g\}$ where $g$ is an element of order $2$, and $\{e,g\}\sim\{e,h\}$ are conjugate subgroups if and only if $g\sim h$ are conjugate elements, so you're really only worried about elements of order two here.

The key is linear algebra: any matrix is similar to its [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), a block diagonal matrix whose blocks are Jordan blocks. If a matrix has order two (or even finite order), what can you say about the Jordan blocks, in particular their sizes and the associated eigenvalues?

[In general, two Jordan normal forms are similar if and only if they have the multiset of Jordan blocks, possibly permuted. The multiset of Jordan blocks is an invariant of the matrix because it encodes the isomorphism type of the vector space as a module over the polynomial ring $\Bbb C[T]$, where $T$ acts by the given matrix. Jordan blocks $J_{\lambda,n}$ correspond to indecomposable summands isomorphic to $ \Bbb C[T]/(T-\lambda)^{n+1}$.]